# SELECT WHERE any value in csv in array

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have this array:

```
$city = ["toronto", "chicago", "potato"];
```

and my table looks like this:

```
Table Name: city_table
id    city
1     toronto, orlando
2     buffalo, toledo
3     orlando, tomato
4     potato, chicago, nanaimo
```

Is it possible to have a query that gives me this result?

```
id    city
1     toronto, orlando
4     potato, chicago, nanaimo
```

I tried this but it obviously doesn't work:

```
$city_string = "'toronto', 'chicago', 'potato'";
SELECT * from city_table WHERE city IN $city_string
```

Comment: Don't use comma-separated values in SQL, normalize your data.

Comment: I'd parse the csv/array into a constructed query and still use `IN`, you could use `FIND_IN_SET` as the answers below suggest, but I am pretty sure it would ignore the benefits of any indexes...actually neither will work, as @Barmar pointed out, you `city` field is loaded with CSVs as well...you're effectively looking for intersecting arrays, with neither array represented effectively.

Comment: I just thought that it'd better to use one column for storing answers to checkboxes separated by commas than to use 20 columns for 20 checkboxes but I guess that's a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search a comma-separated value in MySQL you use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). It can only search for 1 item at a time, so you need to call it separately for each name `$city`, and combine them with `AND`.

```
SELECT *
FROM city_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$city[0]', city_table)
OR FIND_IN_SET('$city[1]', city_table)
OR FIND_IN_SET('$city[2]', city_table)
```

In your actual code you should use `implode()` to construct the WHERE clause dynamically.

Note that you should not have spaces after the commas in the table, `FIND_IN_SET` will not work with the CSV the way you've written it.

However, it would be better to normalize your schema so you don't have a comma-separated value. `FIND_IN_SET` can't be optimized with an index, so it will have to perform a full table scan.

Comment: I changed your query, replacing AND with OR, city_table (in WHERE clause) with city, and removed the spaces as you suggested and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't read your example carefully enough, I thought you wanted all the cities, not just any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` at MySQL.

**Example**

```
SELECT *
FROM city_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$city[0]', city_table)
AND FIND_IN_SET('$city[1]', city_table)
AND FIND_IN_SET('$city[2]', city_table)
```